# Returning XmlDocument from WCF service not working

Tags: wcf, xmldocument, datacontract

I am trying to update some WCF service methods that return strings to return XmlDocument objects. I've tried returning it as-is and encapsulating it in a datacontract object. Either way I'm hitting an error upon attempting to update the service reference. The error suggest encapsulating it in a datacontract with an operations contract which I am doing. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: Trick is : don't do it. Either return the string as is, or even better: why are you returning something clunky like XML?? The point of web services is that they abstract away the XML goo - you should be working with proper business objects (and lists thereof).

Comment: I agree - You should not be returning types like XmlDocument across the wire.

Comment: If you really want to have a solution or answer to your question, I suggest you update your question with examples of your code, the error messages from the compiler etc.

Comment: @marc_s it may be a terminology thing but I assocate "business object" as a domain object which I advise people not to put on service boundaries. Instead I tell people to use data transfer objects to define the message payload and map between these and the domain objects. Using domain objects constrains what you can do in your business layer

Comment: @RichardBlewett: it's definitely just terminology - I was using "business object" as opposed to raw XML. I agree with using DTO's over service boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to return a XmlDocument from WCF, but you need to use the `XmlSerializer` instead of the default serializer (`DataContractSerialier`) - the code below shows how it can be done. Having said that, do consider using data transfer objects as mentioned in the comments, unless your scenario really requires a XmlDocument to be transferred.

```
public class StackOverflow_8951319
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
        [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
        XmlDocument GetDocument();
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }

        public XmlDocument GetDocument()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"<products>
  <product id='1'>
    <name>Bread</name>
  </product>
  <product id='2'>
    <name>Milk</name>
  </product>
  <product id='3'>
    <name>Coffee</name>
  </product>
</products>");
            return doc;
        }
    }
    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        var result = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        //Change binding settings here
        return result;
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), GetBinding(), "");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(GetBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Echo("Hello"));

        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetDocument().OuterXml);

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to pass arbitrary XML on the wire the best way to do it is to use XElement rather than XmlDocument

XmlDocument isn't serializable