# how to return XmlDocument from WCF service?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xmldocument

We  have WCF service. In that a `DataTable` which contains two `ROWS` of record. we converted that `DataTable` to raw `XML`.
Now we want to return that raw `XML` data as `XMLDocument` to client.

we have method like this

```
public System.Xml.XmlDocument ConvertTo(DataTable data)
{
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.WriteXml("Data comes from source");
return xmlDocument;

}
```

And the RAW `XML` data is like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table1>
<ID>1</ID>
</Table1>
<Table2>
<ID>2</ID>
</Table2>
</NewDataSet>
```

Give us suggestion how to return the RAW `XML` data as `XMLDocument` to the Client from `WCF`?

Nayan

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951319/returning-xmldocument-from-wcf-service-not-working

Comment: Is the client .NET?  Why is "raw" XML insufficient?  That's what SOAP uses by default.